# Firebase snapshot.forEach(async () => {}) not working properly

Tags: javascript, firebase, asynchronous

I have a code [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5po2.jpg), that loads posts from firebase collection "posts"
But it does not work the way I expect. There are two documents in collection "posts"
But the result of console.log() is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oi2Jv.jpg). It initially has **0** items, and only after it is populated with two documents. I think that the problem is in this line:

```
const photoUrl = await getDownloadURL(ref(storage, data.photoPath))
```

Because when I remove it, it works fine(array is populated before it is logged in the console, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHwyP.jpg)). Please help!

Comment: I you do not understand something, please write here

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the relevant code as text, do not link paintings of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you need to consider reconstruct your code a little bit. The problem is that the code ends before the asynchronous operations finish. Even though you added `await` when you are trying to download, but the entire operation in the foreach bracket `async (doc) => {....}` is still an asynchronous operation.

What you can do is to reorganize your code into this way:

`const promiseList = []`

`snapShot.forEach(doc => promiseList.push(asyncFunctionToCompleteYourData(doc)))`

`await Promise.all(promiseList)`

Besides, you probably needs to check your lint rules, because usually for JavaScript it should directly throw an error if you are directly writing async code in a for loop.

Comment: I modified my code the way you said, but now my array promiseList contains promises!

Comment: Finally I fixed it, by writing `const list = await Promise.all(promiseList)`